# Opens not registered for Android push notifications

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android, app-development

We have implemented Android and iOS SDK's in Marketing Cloud, but for some reason, opens for Android devices are not registered.
After multiple support cases, we are still in the same scenario, we know nothing about the reason why opens are not registered.
Until now, they provided to us the documentation for implementing multiple push providers and at a certain point they told us that having priority 1 for Marketing Cloud SDK instead of priority 0, could be the problem, but anyone was not able to explain how this priority affects analytics, or what we have to change in our code.

Did someone encounter the same issue?
If yes, how did you solve this?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please provide me the support case numbers -- and sadly, if they've been closed to long, I might ask you to open another. If it comes to that I'll have you ask them to at-mention me, but first let me see what you've already got on file.

Comment: The case number is #44588239. This is the last one, is still open. The case has all the details, including logs for sdk state and everything they asked for. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: See #2 below. You are providing a `builder` for `notification options`. You're probably missing the call to https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/javadocs/MarketingCloudSdk/8.0/com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications/-notification-manager/redirect-intent-for-analytics.html

Comment: We have the call to redirect for analytics, I'll attach the method in Case comments.

Comment: Also attach logs please: Send a push, click the push (which should open your app), close your app, capture the logs.

Comment: We have logs attached to the Case, should I attach them again? or perform another push test?

Comment: I see only the SDK state output. There are no logs.

Comment: I have attached the logs to the case. thanks

Comment: Reviewed, however, I do not see any indication that the collected analytics were transmitted. Please repeat this task and background the application. You will see `Behavior found: BEHAVIOR_APP_BACKGROUNDED` in the logs followed by something similar to `ET_ANALYTICS request took 579ms with code: 201`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a limited set of causes for this behavior:

1. Analytics aren't enabled
2. You've overridden notification handling and have not added the analytic attribution call
3. You're a Multiple Push Provider implementation and another library is displaying/handling the push notification

One gut check for you would be this: look in the `LogCat` for `ET_ANALYTICS` entries after you put the application into the background. That'll tell you whether or not usage analytics are getting off the device: App Open, Time in App, etc.

If you're collecting and sending analytics at all, then either #2 or #3 above is true.